# SharePoint Validation formula help

Tags: list, validation-list-items

I am attempting to make a condition where someone is inputting a new item on a list but for three specific fields, end users can only fill in one of those three. I can't figure out the formula syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: What are those three fields exactly(single line of text or something else). Can you please clarify your question giving more details?

Comment: The fields are three different choice fields.. We are having an issue where individuals are filling in 2/3 of the fields. We want to minimize this error so the individual can only pick ONE field to fill in. Mind you that there are other fields but these particular ones, only one of the three fields can be filled in. Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PreSaveAction() on new form of list to validate these fields using script editor or adding content editor web part.

[Here](http://www.knowledgewalls.com/gopal/books/microsoft-sharepoint-2013/how-to-create-script-editor-webpart-in-sharepoint-2013) is how to add script editor in sharepoint.

You can find more details about content editor, [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/content-editor-web-part-c1350ff6-934c-4c2e-8e53-1ec3b548a0dc).

And [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/use-of-presaveaction-function-on-list-forms-in-sharepoint-20) how to use PreSaveAction().

Comment: My work does not allow third party applications.. Would you roughly know the formula?

Comment: you dont have to use any third party applications for this. you need to add just single javascript file.